# Intercept c++ class constructor with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c++, constructor, ld-preload

I followed [this example](https://gist.github.com/mooware/1174572) to intercept C++ functions in a class.

However now I want to intercept a constructor and desctructor of the class, not just member functions.

In the example, he does `typedef unsigned int (Foo::*methodType)() const;`. I don't think you can typedef constructors/destructors in c++.

How do I do this?

Comment: This is a horrible hack, but I would guess that a constructor or destructor behaves like a `void (Foo::*method)()` methods and could be faked as such. A bit of testing with a disassembler, or some research into your platform's ABI, should be able to confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried 
`typedef void (QDBusConnection::*MyFunction)();` and it works, I can call it with `(this->*origMethod)();` even though origMethod is a destructor and has no return specifier.

I wrote my steps on how to do intercept destructor and static class functions here

http://www.osletek.com/learning-center/150/Intercepting_C%2B%2B_functions_using_LD_PRELOAD